complete/compgen fails to suggest when options contain ':' (colon)
I'm failing to get complete to offer full suggestions when the options in ${COMPREPLY[@]} contain a : character.  Instead, it only offers the prefix that is common to all suggestions.
Here's an example that works fine:
_foo()
{
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "bart baze" -- "$cur" ) )
}
complete -F _foo foo

And here's how it is used (I never press Enter, only TAB where indicated)
$ foo <tab>
$ foo ba       <-- Autocompletes common prefix, good

$ foo ba<tab>
bart baze      <-- Suggests options, good

$ foo bar<tab>
$ foo bart     <-- Autocompletes the only option, good

But if I prepend something with a :, like http://, it fails to provide full suggestions (only the prefix common to all options):
$ _foo()
{
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "h:bart h:baze" -- "$cur" ) )
}
$ complete -F _foo foo

$ foo <tab>
$ foo h:ba         <-- Autocompletes common prefix, good

$ foo h:ba<tab>
$ foo h:ba         <-- No effect

The manual suggests something about -I working with delimiters, but complete -I -F _foo foo doesn't change anything.

If I inspect deeper, it seems to be with how complete -F interprets ${COMPREPLY[@]}.  compgen seems to set COMPREPLY just fine.
$ COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "h:bart h:baze" -- h) )
$ for i in "${COMPREPLY[@]}"; do echo "$i"; done
h:bart
h:baze


Try removing ":" from var  $COMP_WORDBREAKS if it is in there.

@meuh's comment led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528695/how-to-reset-comp-wordbreaks-without-affecting-other-completion-script which led me to the answer.
Bash provides a number of macros to help in /etc/bash_completion.  In debian, this sources /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion.
Browsing in this file there are some ways to handle the colon:

_init_completion -n : will remove : from $COMP_WORDBREAKS.  But calling only this isn't enough, or you'll find ^.*: gets repeated in your auto-complete result
$ _foo()
{
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
  _init_completion -n : cur
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "h:bart h:baze" -- "$cur" ) )
}
$ complete -F _foo foo

$ foo <tab>
$ foo h:h:ba


__ltrim_colon_completions will remove leading ^.*: from the completion, which fixes the previous problem a bit.
The result is:
$ _foo()
{
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
  _init_completion -n : cur
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "h:bart h:baze" -- "$cur" ) )
  __ltrim_colon_completions "$cur"
}
$ complete -F _foo foo

$ foo <tab>
$ foo h:ba       <-- It got the common part right!

$ foo h:ba<tab>
bart baze        <-- It removed the prefix?

$ foo h:baz<tab>
$ foo h:baze     <-- The final completion is correct



The suggestions are a bit strange, especially if you were expecting http://example.com and get //example.com, but it does work.
But the documentation for __ltrim_colon_completions() says:

The preferred solution is to remove the colon (:) from COMP_WORDBREAKS in your .bashrc:
# Remove colon (:) from list of word completion separators                 
COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//:}                                      
                                                                     

See also: Bash FAQ - E13) Why does filename completion misbehave if a colon appears in the filename? - https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ

I'm not really a fan of imposing on /etc/bash.bashrc, especially since this completion script will be deployed in a package, and I'm not making local edits.  This change could also change the behaviour of other completion scripts that actually rely on the : separator for parsing things like $PATH.

The solution I ended up with is to set this in my /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/foo script:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
_foo() {
  COMP_WORDBREAKS=${COMP_WORDBREAKS//:}
  local cur=${COMP_WORDS[$COMP_CWORD]}
  COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "h:bart h:baze" -- "$cur" ) )
}
complete -F _foo foo

It's hard to tell if this has a global impact.  A new shell doesn't have $COMP_WORDBREAKS defined, but I'm not sure if bash-completion reset it between completions.
